# Deferred and promise function does not work correctly

Tags: javascript, jquery

My requirement is pretty simple, but still not able to work out, what is wrong in my code.
I have validate function, which fetch data from server. I want to make sure that It should wait till ajax request finish. Please suggest which deferred function to use.

```
 // Validate function is defined under variable.....

 validate : function (field){
   field.valid = false;
   // accessSer is a common object where AJAX request defined
    accessSer.request("checkDuplicate", field.value, function(response){
     if(response.success == true){
          field.valid = true;
     }
    });
  }


 //i tried below deferred function $.when to call validate function.


 $.when(opts.validate(this)).then( function(){
                console.log(this.valid); // always have undefined
            });

 console.log(field.valid); // always have false.
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to return `accessSer.request(...)` result from validate function. Try something like this instead:

```
validate: function (field) {
    field.valid = false;
    return accessSer.request("checkDuplicate", field.value, function (response) {
        return field.valid = (response.success == true);
    });
}

opts.validate(this).then(function (valid) {
    console.log(valid);
    console.log(field.valid);
});
```

Comment: Does not work, syntax error at opts.validate(this).then(function (valid)

Comment: But surprising , It still call validate function.